# How to create a news feed like Facebook using Django, Tastypie, Redis and the task queue Gearman?

Tags: django, redis, tastypie, feed, python-gearman

Can anyone recommend or create a tutorial on how to make a news feed similar to that of Facebook's only using Django, Tastypie (webservice API framework for Django), Redis (key-value store) and Gearman (task queue)?

Currently I have user model, post model, favorites model and a comment model. I have created Tastypie resources with these models to allow for favoriting, liking, commenting and posting.

I would like to know how to generate feed actions that apply directly to the user. For example:

```
User1 commented on your post. (2 seconds ago)
User2 liked your post. (3 mins ago)
User2 & User1 favorited your post (5 mins ago)
```

I really require in depth examples and tutorials on how to build an activity feed using the technologies above. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an activity stream with the app [django-activity-stream](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream).

Comment: can I use django-activity-stream with Redis? and also if the action is reversed, am I able to delete the activity?

Comment: You can use Redis as the cache. Since the activities are stored in the database/cache, yes, you can delete those too using signals for example.

Comment: One thing to note about that project is that it doesn't work when a new user is following a particular action creator. Facebook would show previous feeds in situations like this.